# How to make an adjacency table

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, chord-diagram

I have similar data

```
mydf <- data.frame(p1=c('a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d'),
                   p2=c('b','c','d','c','d','e','d','e','e'),
                   p3=c('a','a','c','c','d','d','d','a','a'),
                   p4=c('a','a','b','c','c','e','d','a','b'),
                   p5=c('a','b','c','d','e','b','b','c','c'),
                   source=c('a','b','c','d','e','e','a','b','d'))
```

Which gives:

```
   p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 source
1  a  b  a  a  a      a
2  a  c  a  a  b      b
3  a  d  c  b  c      c
4  b  c  c  c  d      d
5  b  d  d  c  e      e
6  b  e  d  e  b      e
7  c  d  d  d  b      a
8  c  e  a  a  c      b
9  d  e  a  b  c      d
```

I want to create two adjacency matrix as, number of connections between source to rest columns.For example:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  
a  4  2
b  5  1
c  1  1
d  1  2
e  0  3
```

Is there any way to do it easily. Would appreciate any help

Comment: `do.call(table, df[1:2])` will produce that for `col1` and `col2`, with one fixable difference: the row names and column names are a-f, but your `col1` column is not in the output. (But I can't really be sure without `set.seed`.)

Comment: Can you check revised questions @RonakShah

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake and I corrected now. I counted from source to rest columns. in "a" to "a", for example, there are four unidirectional connections between a to a in row 1 (columns -p1, p3, p4 and p5) and none in rest rows. In second, "a" to "b", there are five unidirectional connections (row 2, column p1, p3 and p4, plus row 8, column p3 and p4). Hope it is clear now. @RonakShah

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer. @RonakShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can use `unlist` and `table` :

```
table(rep(mydf$source, ncol(mydf) - 1), unlist(mydf[-ncol(mydf)]))

#    a b c d e
#  a 4 2 1 3 0
#  b 5 1 3 0 1
#  c 1 1 2 1 0
#  d 1 2 4 2 1
#  e 0 3 1 3 3
```

---

Another approach could be to get the data in long format, `count` based on `source` and get data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -source) %>%
  count(source, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))

#  source     a     b     c     d     e
#  <fct>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 a          4     2     1     3     0
#2 b          5     1     3     0     1
#3 c          1     1     2     1     0
#4 d          1     2     4     2     1
#5 e          0     3     1     3     3
```

Comment: The code worked well in example data. When I used the the codes in the big data, I did not get an adjacency table. Unlike example, the column names were numbers (not string). The adjacency matrix should have equal rows and columns. Would be greatly appreciate your help @ronak-shah

Comment: Please share example which represents your actual data so that it is easier to help.

Comment: Thanks. Data is available here <a href="https://send.firefox.com/download/8b724d5adbfc0ac9/#qoXT9wCz-HGRqDGezYXHyw">file</a>

Comment: It says "Link is expired".

Comment: Strange. Please find data here [link] (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9786c272444af9e474325f51009679f820200406073155/23b0f8) 'code' NA denotes no data

Comment: @Discovery2020 I loaded the data in `Samples` and used `Samples %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = COL1:COL798, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  count(source, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))` which worked for me. Can you check if that is what you want.

Comment: It worked. However, I wanted to have a square matrix by listing column names to row (make same number) (similar to correlation matrix) and count value from source to column as you did.

Comment: @Discovery2020 `Samples %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = COL1:COL798, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  count(source, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(source)) %>%
  column_to_rownames('source')`

Comment: No, it did not work. I need a square matrix where row and column name should be unique value (string) of Samples (not only those of sources). Value should be count from from source to other columns as you did previously.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could look my issue

Comment: Probably it is better if you ask a new question with all the up-to-date information.